# Android Google Map V2 gives ZERO_RESULTS

Tags: android, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google map API in my android application where I drawn suggestion line while select source and destination. But sometime the google API Response gives ZERO_RESULTS. So I could not draw the suggestion line.

**Post Json**
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=12.8247072,80.2139655&destination=16.04141453828351,78.81681315600872&sensor=false&mode=driving&language=en-EN

**Google API Response**

```
 {   "geocoded_waypoints" : [ {}, {} ],   "routes" : [],   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"}
```

Somehow I need to draw the direction line at least nearby destination.  Anyone Please help me to resolve this issues. 
[image]

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Seems there is still no route available between these 2 points, even you try [with the browser](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/12.8247072,80.2139655/'16.04141453828351,78.81681315600872'/@14.4474712,75.0764647,6z/data=!4m8!4m7!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x0:0x0!2m2!1d78.8168132!2d16.0414145), the destination is inside a forest, so Google Maps probably could not provide any result for you. You can try search some point of interest around that area, and use that as your destination.

Comment: @Budius,   Somehow I need to draw the suggestion line at least nearby destination instead of showing without line.